# Data tag parsing failed: unbalanced quotation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When executing the following command, I get the error "Data tag parsing failed: unbalanced quotation"

```
/give @p leather_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Nightslash Helm",Lore:["Legendary helmet found only in a secret hideout."]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:9999},{id:1,lvl:99999},{id:2,lvl:99999},{id:3,lvl:999999},{id:4,lvl:999999},{id:5,lvl:99999},{id:6,lvl:999},{id:7,lvl:99}],Unbreakable:1}
```

I don't see why the command would be wrong. What should I change for this error to go away?

Comment: Testing this command in Minecraft 1.8.8/vanilla gives me the correct item. Make sure that you copy/pasted the right command and that you did not leave errand characters in the command block.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, because the problem can not be reproduced.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using standard Minecraft chat for this, it's not going to work, due to the character limit of the chat.

You'll have to run this command in a command block, that has a far, far higher limit.